# In Boostrap 4, how do I prevent the form label from aligning right in?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I made a form in Bootstrap 4. However, the label for "Number of Travellers" is aligned right, instead of left, which makes the form look odd and label out of place.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="form-row col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label for="travelFrom">Travelling from:</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Singapore" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label for="travelTo">Travelling to:</label>
                      <select class="form-control" id="to">
                        <option>Indonesia</option>
                        <option>Malaysia</option>
                        <option>Thailand</option>
                        <option>Hong Kong</option>
                        <option>South Korea</option>
                        <option>Japan</option>
                        <option>Maldives</option>
                        <option>Others</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Number of Travellers:</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the number of travellers">
                    </div>
                    <a href="https://m.me/weekendgowheresg" class="fb-msg-btn" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn.snaptravel.com/facebook-messenger-white.svg" style="width:30px;height:30px" alt="Facebook Messenger logo">Get Deal on Messenger</a>
                    <a href="https://wa.me/93900052" class="wa-msg-btn" target="_blank"><img src="images/whatsapp.svg" style="width:30px;height:30px" alt="WhatsApp logo">Get Deal on WhatsApp</a>
                </div>
```

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

I wish to make it such that the label, "Number of Travellers" is directly above the input box.

All help is appreciated!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/or7jd8yL/

Comment: post your css as well or better create demo here so we can have a look

Comment: please create a working code snippet of your code. thanks

Comment: you need to show your all code with css..

Comment: I have added a JSFiddle link for my code.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer below structure as this is how you should create structure

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 
    
    
    
    <form>
      <div class="form-row form-group">
        <div class="col">
           <label for="travelFrom">Travelling from:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Singapore" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
         <label>Label</label>
           <select class="form-control" id="to">
                <option>Indonesia</option>
                <option>Malaysia</option>
                <option>Thailand</option>
                <option>Hong Kong</option>
                <option>South Korea</option>
                <option>Japan</option>
                <option>Maldives</option>
                <option>Others</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row form-group">
        <div class="col">
         <label>Number of Travellers:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the number of travellers">
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </form>
    
    
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your use of form-row is incorrect. You have not pasted the entire code code block only a partial one. So I have to make some assumptions, like is it wrapped with container, or container-fluid? What css are you using? etc?

If you are using container-fluid, columns will be wrapped to take up the correct space, however you should not really rely on the bootsrap working out the layout if you really do intent the items to be on a different row.

I used your code, and when implemented I get the following:

[image]

As your can see number of travelers is squashed, but does not align the heading to the right as in your example. Implying something else in your code is moving it to the right (css, or outer html). Ignoring that and changing your code to correctly use rows and columns produces the intended output, not taking the css into account of course:

[image]

First we need to divide the screen into two, one for the form and one for your image:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
            Your form goes here
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
            Cell phone image here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The form which is inside the first column is as follows:

```
<form>
</form>
```

This should have three rows:

```
<form>
   <div class="form-row">
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
   </div>
</form>
```

Each row will have its items or form-group items:

```
<form>
   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group">
          Must be half the size col 6, must have a label and an input
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          Must be half the size col 6, must have a label and an input
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group">
          Must be the full row hence col 12, must have a label and an input
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
      Pattern continues.
   </div>
</form>
```

Therefore, your code should look something like this:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="travelFrom">Travelling from:</label>
      <input
        class="form-control"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Singapore"
        readonly
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="travelTo">Travelling to:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="to">
          <option>Indonesia</option>
          <option>Malaysia</option>
          <option>Thailand</option>
          <option>Hong Kong</option>
          <option>South Korea</option>
          <option>Japan</option>
          <option>Maldives</option>
          <option>Others</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label>Number of Travellers:</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Enter the number of travellers"
            />
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <a href="https://m.me/weekendgowheresg" class="fb-msg-btn" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://cdn.snaptravel.com/facebook-messenger-white.svg"
          style="width:30px;height:30px"
          alt="Facebook Messenger logo"/>Get Deal on Messenger</a>
      <a href="https://wa.me/93900052" class="wa-msg-btn" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/whatsapp.svg" style="width:30px;height:30px" alt="WhatsApp logo"/>Get Deal on WhatsApp</a>
    </div>
  </form>  
</form> 
    <div class='col-md-6'>
       Cell phone image here
    </div>
  </div>
```

Naturally this container-fluid will all be at the top of the screen which you can fix using either flex layout or auto margins.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. However, this is what happens when I implement your code: https://i.imgur.com/QbeZ4od.jpg

As you can see the app slider is no longer on the right hand side of the form, and the two buttons, which are supposed to be under the form (i.e. last row) are now on the right side.

Comment: The two buttons can be moved below by making another row. As for the slider it means that the html that wraps this code is incorrect.

Comment: @paoye The reason the image is now underneath is because form form-row should be wrapped. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

use a class `col-md` on Number of travelers 'form-group' like,

```html
<div class="form-group col-md">
    <label>Number of Travellers:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the number of travellers">
</div>
```

Comment: When I do that, the `<label>Number of Travellers:</label>` right aligns.

Comment: Inspect the `<label>` code on browser with development tools and see the related css and compare other `<label>` css. in your code I see only difference is other label has `for` attribute but not the label. if there has a css with attribute like `label[for]` you can add an `for` attribute on the label

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap provides a `.text-left` for aligning text to the left. Add this class to the container of that form-group. This will pull the text to the left instead of aligning it to the center (which you probably have declared somewhere in your custom css)

Comment: .text-left would work, however it is fixing a symptom and not the problem. In this case bootstrap always aligns labels to the input within a form-group. Something else is wrong, using .text-left is therefore a hack, and could induce unintended consequences.

Comment: @Jason as I wrote in my answer, you've got custom css declared somewhere that is interfering... Yeah it's a hack, but at least it should provide a workaround for your custom css.

Comment: true, I am however a proponent of solving the issue :)